# Apache2 Let's Encrypt 404 for .well-known/acme-challenge

Tags: apache2, lets-encrypt

I am trying to issue a Lts encrypt ssl on my Apache2 AWS ECS.

I confirmed the www and non www versions of the domain are all pointed correctly to the server however I receive an error that I am not sure how to fix.

```
Type:   unauthorized
Detail: Invalid response from http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/VR1csQL-Tp-tPMqMtmG1EcLWncgxMdov4MGZgq2RqQY
[3.210.25.136]: "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML
2.0//EN\">\n<html><head>\n<title>404 Not
Found</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Not Found</h1>\n<p"
```

My virtual host file looks like this

```
<VirtualHost my-ip-here:80>

    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example

    <Directory /var/www/example>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias /.well-known/acme-challenge/ /var/www/example/.well-known/acme-challenge/
    <Directory /var/www/example/.well-known/acme-challenge/>
      AllowOverride None
      Require all granted
      Satisfy Any
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com-access.log combined

  </VirtualHost>
```